# Mouse move host listener sometimes not listening on child component angular 2

Tags: angular

I am having mouse move host listener in my child component.

I am calling this child in parent component.But when user moves the  mouse ,some times mouse move is not detecting.But If I move the host listener code to parent component its detecting mouse move seamlessly

```
@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
@HostListener('touchmove', ['$event'])
onmousemove(e: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("mousemove demo events",e.clientX,e.clientY) 


}
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys.

I have found the problem .
The host listener I have added was specific to the scope of my child component,so outside the component it was not detecting the mouse move.
So I have added
     ng-content
 in my child and called my parent html content inside the child so now its detecting the mouse move.For example

```
<child>
<div>test</div> //Parent component html
</child>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to bubble the event up to the parent (from the child).

In your child component:

```
@Output() mouseMoveEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

then in the child component catch the onmousemove event and emit it:

```
this.mouseMoveEmitter.emit(e);
```

In your parent html you can catch the emitted event as followed:

```
<your-child-component (mouseMoveEmitter)="onmousemove($event)"</your-child-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
@HostListener('touchmove', ['$event'])
onmousemove(e: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("mousemove demo events",e.clientX,e.clientY) 
}
```

Have you used this method before? Where you combine touch and mouse events? I have never seen it, and I can't say for certain it won't work, but I was always under the impression that they were separate event types. TouchEvents are their own typescript class. I've always accessed touch position with :

```
event.changedTouches[0].clientX, event.changedTouches[0].clientY
```

Rather than just clientX / clientY. I suppose the browser might be doing something to wrap or translate them into the same thing though.